# int * const AND extern int *

Tags: c

There's two C Language flies.
`main.c`:

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int * a;
extern int d;

int main(){
    printf("==> a==>%p\n", a);
    printf("==>&a==>%p\n", &a);
    printf("==>%zd\n", *a);
    printf("======================\n");

    int c = 5;
    a = &c;

    printf("==> a==>%p\n", a);
    printf("==>&a==>%p\n", &a);
    printf("==>%zd\n", *a);
    printf("======================\n");

    d = 5;
    printf("==>%d\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

`global.c`:

```
// global.c
int b = 1;
int * const a = &b;
int const d = 1;
```

I run the command `cc main.c global.c` and `./a.out`,Then I find the variable `a`'s value can be changed, and the variable `d`'s value can't be changed.
Why?

Comment: You defined `d` as constant in global.c , it's only visible to main.c, you cannot alter the value.

Comment: @ErYe Can you elaborate a bit on "Can't be changed"? Are you getting a compiler error (unlikely, as you are tricking the compiler into thinking `d` would be writable)? A linker error (maybe, if you are using a C++ compiler) or a core dump (more likely, as const allows the linker to put the variable into a non-writable segment)

Comment: "*Then I find the variable a's value can be changed*" how? And also what does the program print out?

Comment: OT: `zd` is for `ssize_t`, you pass an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using :

```
int const a=10;
```

the value of a remains constant throughout the execution of program.

Using:

```
int* const a=&b;
```

The value contained by a i.e. the address of b remains constant throughout.

The value of b can change.

Comment: My code is `int * const a = &b;`, but not `const int* a=&b;`  And in the `mian.c` file, the `a`'s value can be changed.

Comment: In the `main.c` file, why I can change `a = &c;`?

Comment: I think his point is that if `d` is defined in two compilation units, one declaring it as `extern int` and the other as `const int`, the compiler has no way of knowing these differences across compilation units. I am curious too.

Comment: My gcc 4.9 compiled version of the code shown crashes in both cases: `a= ...` as well as `d=...`.